# RxJs combine http request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying combine two HTTP requests in rxjs help to combine the requests, but the parameters(accountId, userId) of the second request are in the response of the first request.

```
a = http.get<any>(...);
b = http.get<any>(... +  '/' + accountId + '/' + userId})

concat(a, b).subscribe(res => {});
```

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using? 5 or 6?

Comment: @pindev version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mergeMap as you said accountId and userId are in the response of first api request.

```
a.pipe(
 mergeMap(data => b(data.accountId,data.userId))
).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

where you should define b as something which returns the observable

```
b(accountId userId): Observable<any> {
 return http.get<any>(... +  '/' + accountId + '/' + userId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) to combine multiple subscriptions.

```
forkJoin([a, b]).subscribe((res) => {
  // res[0] should be the response of `a`
  // res[1] should be the response of `b`
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the data down the through aResponse.

```
a = http.get<any>(...);
b = http.get<any>(... +  '/' + accountId + '/' + userId})
const getBFromA$ = a.pipe(
    switchMap((aResponse) => {
        const accountId = aResponse.accountId;
        const userId = aResponse.userId;
        return http.get<any>(... +  '/' + accountId + '/' + userId})
    }).subscribe((bResponseOnly) => { // do something if you want to })
```